# Image alternate text for html 1

Tags: html, backwards-compatibility

Is it possible to use alternate text in an <img> tag in html in a way that is compatible with html 1(ignoring tags it doesn't understand).  Would <img src="image_source" alt="alt text"> alt text </img> be valid?  More importantly, would it display correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  <img src="image_source" alt="alt text" /> <!-- >alt text < --> works.  The space between <!-- and >, and < and --> are so Internet Explorer doesn't think that they are broken conditional comments and try to display the alt text.

A modern browser sees the same thing as:

<img src="image_source" alt="alt text" /> <!-- A comment -->

Old(html 1) browsers see:
<busted_tag busted_atribut="broken" bad_atribute="busted"> <bad_tag>alt text<broken_tag>